# Same file, multiple tabs, pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I've recently started using pycharm. I really like it, but there's one feature that would make it much better.

I'd like to be able to open two tabs both with the same file, just at different locations (for example one tab with a.txt on line 100 and another with a.txt on 200). But right now pycharm won't let me open multiple of the same files.

I can get something similar by doing a vertical split, but obviously that's not ideal, as the screen gets cluttered pretty quickly.

This would help so much with debugging when tracing through function calls.

Answer (score 3):

You can!
Click with the right button on a opened tab, and select "split vertically".

Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Right-click your tab, and click <kbd>Open in Opposite Group</kbd>

[image: PyCharm]